# Update watsonplatform.net endpoint for sentiment analysis, getting 404

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, sentiment-analysis

I updated the Watson end-point as per IBM's email instructions (service credentials URL & api) and when I execute the call, I get a "404 Not Found".

Url is

```
https://api.eu-gb.natural-language-understanding.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/2xxxxx43-52ac-4xx5-922d-cxxxxx5ea52b
```

EDIT:
This is the test I am doing (and the same code I used for analysing text in live environment):

```
    function Analyse($text)
    {
        $body = '{
              "text": "' . addslashes($text) . '",
              "features": {
                "sentiment": {}
              }
            }';

        $url = "https://api.eu-gb.natural-language-understanding.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/2xxxxx43-52ac-4xx5-922d-cxxxxx5ea52b";
        $key = "ukLuEL.........qinV";

        $response = Request::post($url)
            ->authenticateWith('apikey', $key)// authenticate with basic auth...
            ->body($body)
            ->sendsJson()
            ->send();

        $body = $response->body; // <<<<< THIS MESSAGE STATES "NOT FOUND 404"
        $sentiment = $body->sentiment->document;

        return [
            "label" => $sentiment->label,
            "score" => $sentiment->score
        ];
    }
```

If I substitute the old credentials back, it works and returns the sentiment. The old URL is:

```
https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/analyze?version=2018-03-19
```

Comment: Is this the endpoint as shown in your service credentials? https://api.REGION.natural-language-understanding.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/YOUR-INSTANCE-ID should be the correct format. What is the exact call you are trying to perform?

Comment: Precisely, this is the new URL displayed in the service credentials (along with the new key), which is returning a 404 when I substitute it in my code. I am trying to perform sentiment analysis on a piece of string using HTTP POST.

Comment: Add your full code / context to the question. It is not clear how you call it. Which API are you calling? https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/natural-language-understanding#introduction

Comment: Original post edited to contain code sample

Comment: But where do you compose the full path? See my link, you still need to add the API path

Comment: I feel a bit sheepish now. That's working now. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I added it as answer, so we can close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to not substitue the old full path with just the base URI. See the [API docs for IBM Watson Natural Language Understanding](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/natural-language-understanding#introduction) for the base URI and the path for the individual API function.

Thus, this URI:

```
https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/analyze?version=2018-03-19
```

should become

```
https://api.eu-gb.natural-language-understanding.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/2xxxxx43-52ac-4xx5-922d-cxxxxx5ea52b//v1/analyze?version=2021-03-25
```